# How to get custom tooltip box on hover inside SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a map in SVG format which shows many cities in it. What I want to do is that whenever mouse hovers on a city, it shows some details which itself should be in HTML div.

Here is the demo of what I want: http://www.nytimes.com/elections/results/senate

I have no clue how to do that, neither I was able to find the answer.
Here is sample code of SVG file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="356 432 235 237">
  <g title="Uttar Pradesh" fill="#ccc">
    <path d="M 402.80505,648.30477 C 400.84581" fill="rgb(255,166,46)"/>
    <path d="M 402.80505,648.30477 C 400.84581" fill="rgb(255,166,46)"/>
    ...
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Here is a page that may be useful to you: http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/interactive-svg-components/tooltip (found with a one minute google search btw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DIV, that is placed over the inline SVG, is the most diversified means of showing data related to an SVG element. The element can be highlighted and the DIV can include the associated data attached to the element. The DIV is positioned at the element taking into consideration the web page scrolled position.
Below is a basic example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>ToolTip With DIV</title>

</head>
<body style='font-family:arial'>
<center>
<b>ToolTip With DIV</b><br /><br />
Below are 3 elements with an onmouseover event and their data attribute.<br />
<br />
<div style='width:90%;background-color:gainsboro;text-align:justify;padding:10px;border-radius:6px;'>
A DIV, that is placed over the inline SVG, is the most diversified means of showing data related to an SVG element. The element can be highlighted and the DIV can
include the associated data attached to the element. The DIV is positioned at the element taking into consideration the web page scrolled position.
</div>
<p></p>
<div id="svgDiv" style='background-color:gainsboro;width:400px;height:400px;'>
<svg id="mySVG" width="400" height="400">
<circle onmouseover=showMyTooltip(evt) cx=150 cy=150 r=60 fill=red stroke="black" stroke-width="0"  data="I am a Circle" />
<rect onmouseover=showMyTooltip(evt)  x=200 y=200 width=60 height=60 fill=lime  data="I am a Rectangle"  stroke="black" stroke-width="0"  />
<ellipse onmouseover=showMyTooltip(evt)  cx=300 cy=300 rx=60 ry=20 fill=blue data="I am an Ellipse"  stroke="black" stroke-width="0"   />
</svg>
</div>
<div id=tooltipDiv style='background:white;padding:5px;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;visibility:hidden'></div>

</body>
<script>

var PreviousElement
//---mouseover element--
function showMyTooltip(evt)
{
    var target = evt.target
   if(!PreviousElement||PreviousElement!=target) //--prevent 'stutter'---
   {
        if(PreviousElement) //---remove highlight (stroke) ---
            PreviousElement.setAttribute('stroke-width',0)

        target.setAttribute('stroke-width',3)
        var myData=target.getAttribute("data")

        tooltipDiv.innerHTML=myData

        var x = evt.clientX;
        var y = evt.clientY;

        var scrollX = window.pageXOffset
        var scrollY = window.pageYOffset

        var divLeft=x+5+scrollX+"px"
        var divTop=y+5+scrollY+"px"

        tooltipDiv.style.left=divLeft
        tooltipDiv.style.top=divTop
        tooltipDiv.style.visibility="visible"
        PreviousElement=target
  }
}

</script>

</html>
```